# How we can know the no of users/tests/samples taken maximum time in summery report or aggregate report?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

with jmeter performance testing. How we can know the no of users taken maximum time in summery report.As we can just know one of the sample taken taken this maximum time but we can not find the no of users or samples faced this maximum time?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can generate a dashboard report using JMeter Command Line : [Generating-Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html). Using either of the following commands, depending upon whether you want to generate after the test completes or at one go.

```
jmeter -n -t <path_to.jmx> -l <log.jtl> -e -o <dashboard_folder>

or

jmeter -g <log.jtl> -o <dashboard_folder>
```

Then Check:

```
Response Time Over Time Graph:
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're looking for [Response Time vs Threads](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesVsThreads/) chart which allows analysis of the correlation of increasing number of threads (virtual users) with increasing response time per request/transaction:

[image]

You can install Response Time vs Threads chart as a part of [`KPI vs KPI Graphs`](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-graphs-vs) bundle using JMeter Plugins Manager

[image]

Comment: as in summery report i can check the max or min time taken by any request but not conclude many samples has taken this number of max or min time , from where i can check that .